# Use Marker GeoCharts in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-visualization

I want to display the markers on GeoChart like this https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?hl=it#marker-geocharts, How can i inject `mapsApiKey` in Google GeoChart using `ng-google-chart` directive.
Example code

```
var chart = {};
chart.type = "GeoChart";
chart.mapsApiKey = 'Generated API Key';
chart.data = [
                     ['City',   'Population', 'Area'],
                     ['Rome',      2761477,    1285.31],
                     ['Milan',     1324110,    181.76],
                     ['Naples',    959574,     117.27],
                     ['Turin',     907563,     130.17],
                     ['Palermo',   655875,     158.9],
                     ['Genoa',     607906,     243.60],
                     ['Bologna',   380181,     140.7],
                     ['Florence',  371282,     102.41],
                     ['Fiumicino', 67370,      213.44],
                     ['Anzio',     52192,      43.43],
                     ['Ciampino',  38262,      11]
                   ];
chart.options = {
    region: 'IT',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
};

$scope.chartInfo = chart;
```

In the HTML

```
<div google-chart chart="chartInfo" id="chart"></div>
```

I am passing **mapsApiKey** along with all other properties.
It always shows **Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError**. Where i need to exactly inject the **mapsApiKey**?

Comment: it needs to be part of the load statement --> `google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['geochart'], mapsApiKey: '...'});`

Comment: you mean i have to include mapsApiKey in the ng-google-chart directive itself?

Comment: most likely, i'm not all that familiar with `ng-google-chart`...

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the mapsApiKey using the [agcGstaticLoaderProvider](http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/1.0.0-beta.1/providers/agcGstaticLoaderProvider/)

This needs to happen when you first bootstrap your AngularJS application. See [this](https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/issues/336) github issue for details on how I am implementing it.